# Cross Domain request withCredentials not working

Tags: html, jquery

I'm developing an authentication website that authenticate data from a web service. My website is running locally and the web service is running on different domain ex: test.abc.com. if authentication is success then store the response in cookies.

if the data is available in cookies and not expired then in the second call do not ask for authentication but need to validate the user from back end. For that i am using below code.

```
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://test.abc.com/test/DummyTest",              
    method:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert(Success);
    },
    error:function(xhr,err){
    alert("Error");
 });
```

I am using jquery1.6

I have checked the browser Options and the cookies are stored with my localhost ip(160.225.230.50) address. but the web service is in different domain(abc.com). while accessing the second time, I got Error response.

Please help out me on this.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work your auth page should send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` headers.

When using `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` you cannot set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to wildcard, but need to specify origin: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://abc.com`

Also, there is a simpler way to set xhr fields:

```
$.ajax({
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: ...
});
```